# NestJS - Combine multiple Guards and activate if one returns true

Tags: nestjs

Is it possible to use multiple auth guards on a route (in my case basic and ldap auth).
The route should be authenticated when one guard was successful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Short answer: No, if you add more than one guard to a route, they all need to pass for the route to be able to activate.

Long answer: What you are trying to accomplish is possible however by making your LDAP guard extend the basic one. If the LDAP specific logic succeeds, return `true`, otherwise return the result of the call to `super.canActivate()`. Then, in your controller, add either the basic or LDAP guard to your routes, but not both.

### basic.guard.ts

```js
export BasicGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
      protected readonly reflector: Reflector
  ) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
     const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
     if () {
        // Do some logic and return true if access is granted
        return true;
     }

    return false;
  }
}
```

### ldap.guard.ts

```js
export LdapGuard extends BasicGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
      protected readonly reflector: Reflector
  ) {
   super(reflector);
}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
     const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
     if () {
        // Do some logic and return true if access is granted
        return true;
     }
    
    // Basically if this guard is false then try the super.canActivate.  If its true then it would have returned already
    return await super.canActivate(context);
  }
}
```

For more information see [this GitHub issue on the official NestJS repository](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/873).

Answer (score 24):

### According to AuthGuard it just works out of the box

#### AuthGuard definition

If you look at AuthGuard then you see the following definition:

(File is node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.d.ts)

```js
export declare const AuthGuard: (type?: string | string[]) => Type<IAuthGuard>;
```

That means that AuthGuard can receive an array of strings.

#### Code

In my code I did the following:

```js
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard(["jwt", "api-key"]))
  @Get()
  getOrders() {
    return this.orderService.getAllOrders();
  }
```

#### Postman test

In Postman, the endpoint can have the api-key and the JWT.

- Tested with JWT in Postman Authorization: It works
- Tested with API-Key in Postman Authorization: It works

That implies there is an OR function between the 2 Guards.

Comment: Great and simple solution! This works for me too.

Comment: for some reason iI found that the order of `["jwt", "api-key"]` matters. `["api-key", "jwt"]` did NOT work

Answer (score 9):

You can create an abstract guard, and pass instances or references there, and return true from this guard if any of the passed guards returned true.

Let's imagine you have 2 guards: `BasicGuard` and `LdapGuard`. And you have a controller `UserController` with route `@Get()`, which should be protected by these guards.

So, we can create an abstract guard `MultipleAuthorizeGuard` with next code:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MultipleAuthorizeGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector, private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef) {}

  public canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Observable<boolean> {
    const allowedGuards = this.reflector.get<Type<CanActivate>[]>('multipleGuardsReferences', context.getHandler()) || [];

    const guards = allowedGuards.map((guardReference) => this.moduleRef.get<CanActivate>(guardReference));

    if (guards.length === 0) {
      return of(true);
    }

    if (guards.length === 1) {
      return guards[0].canActivate(context) as Observable<boolean>;
    }

    const checks$: Observable<boolean>[] = guards.map((guard) =>
      (guard.canActivate(context) as Observable<boolean>).pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          if (err instanceof UnauthorizedException) {
            return of(false);
          }
          throw err;
        }),
      ),
    );

    return forkJoin(checks$).pipe(map((results: boolean[]) => any(identity, results)));
  }
}
```

As you can see, this guard doesn't contain any references to a particular guard, but only accept the list of references. In my example, all guards return `Observable`, so I use `forkJoin` to run multiple requests. But of course, it can be adopted to Promises as well.

To avoid initiating `MultipleAuthorizeGuard` in the controller, and pass necessary dependencies manually, I'm left this task to Nest.js and pass references via custom decorator `MultipleGuardsReferences`

```js
export const MultipleGuardsReferences = (...guards: Type<CanActivate>[]) =>
  SetMetadata('multipleGuardsReferences', guards);
```

So, in controller we can have next code:

```js
@Get()
@MultipleGuardsReferences(BasicGuard, LdapGuard)
@UseGuards(MultipleAuthorizeGuard)
public getUser(): Observable<User> {
  return this.userService.getUser();
}
```

Comment: Your metadata keys do not match. You need to change 'allowedGuards' to 'multipleGuardsReferences' in the first line of canActivate method.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll fix the example

Comment: Thank you @SergiyVoznyak for your valuable input!

Comment: You can also let the `MultipleGuardsReferences` decorator set `UseGuards(MultipleAuthorizeGuard)`, so you only need `@MultipleGuardsReferences(BasicGuard, LdapGuard)` on your controller.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a npm package that address this scenario: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nest-lab/or-guard.

Then you call a unique guard that references all the necessary guards as parameters:

```
guards([useGuard('basic') ,useGuard('ldap')])
```

Answer (score 2):

> Inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69966319/16730890

This uses Promise instead of Observable.

```
import {
  CanActivate,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  SetMetadata,
  Type,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ModuleRef, Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';

@Injectable()
export class MultipleAuthorizeGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private readonly reflector: Reflector,
    private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef,
  ) {}

  public async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const allowedGuards =
      this.reflector.get<Type<CanActivate>[]>(
        'multipleGuardsReferences',
        context.getHandler(),
      ) || [];

    const guards = allowedGuards.map((guardReference) =>
      this.moduleRef.get<CanActivate>(guardReference),
    );

    if (guards.length === 0) {
      return Promise.resolve(true);
    }

    if (guards.length === 1) {
      return guards[0].canActivate(context) as Promise<boolean>;
    }

    return Promise.any(
      guards.map((guard) => {
        return guard.canActivate(context) as Promise<boolean>;
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

```
export const MultipleGuardsReferences = (...guards: Type<CanActivate>[]) =>
  SetMetadata('multipleGuardsReferences', guards);
```

```
@Get()
@MultipleGuardsReferences(BasicGuard, LdapGuard)
@UseGuards(MultipleAuthorizeGuard)
public getUser(): Promise<User> {
  return this.userService.getUser();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use combo guard that injects all guards what you need and combines their logic.
There is closed github issue:
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/873