# Nestjs execute provider without providing it in module

Tags: javascript, typescript, authentication, nestjs

I have a module which is exporting all sorts of auth related guards. And I had made a guard which can execute multiple guard inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72804800/17097699).

But whenever i try to execute, nestjs always gives me an error saying
 `ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Nest could not find AdminGuard element (this provider does not exist in the current context)`.

How can i achive it without providing that guards in that module?

My sample code

`AuthModule`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [PrismaModule],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    DummyGuard,
    AdminGuard,
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [DummyGuard, AdminGuard],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

My another module which is using that AuthModule

```js
@Module({
  imports: [PrismaModule, AuthModule],
  providers: [StatsService],
  controllers: [StatsController],
})
export class StatsModule {}
```

My controller in StatModule

```js
@Controller('stats')
export class StatsController {
  constructor(private readonly statsService: StatsService) {}

  @MultipleGuardsReferences(AdminGuard, DummyGuard)
  @UseGuards(MultipleAuthorizeGuard)
  @Get('dummy')
  dummy() {
    return {
      ok: true,
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting strict to false while getting the module fixed it.

```js
@Injectable()
export class MultipleAuthorizeGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private readonly reflector: Reflector,
    private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef
  ) {}

  public async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const allowedGuards =
      this.reflector.get<Type<CanActivate>[]>(
        MULTIPLE_GUARDS_REFERENCES_KEY,
        context.getClass()
      ) || [];

    const guards = allowedGuards.map((guardReference) =>
      this.moduleRef.get<CanActivate>(guardReference, { strict: false })
    );

    if (guards.length === 0) {
      return Promise.resolve(true);
    }

    if (guards.length === 1) {
      return guards[0].canActivate(context) as Promise<boolean>;
    }

    return Promise.any(
      guards.map((guard) => {
        return guard.canActivate(context) as Promise<boolean>;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

You can check here for more options [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).